# Sql XML Node unique ID for connection head rows to item rows

Tags: sql, unpivot, row-number, sql-server-openxml

We have an XML as the following (MS Sql Server)

```
<Features>
  <Item>
   <Description>First Descr.</Description>
   <Comment>First comment</Comment>
   <C0001>12</C0001>
   <C0002>23</C0002>
  </Item>   
  <Item>
   <Description>Second Descr.</Description>
   <Comment>Second comment</Comment>
   <C0001>212</C0001>
   <C0002>223</C0002>
   <C0003>323</C0003>
  </Item>   
</Features>
```

We want to select these data into two separated table: Head and Items:

Head rows (expected)

```
HeadID |  Description   | Comment 
1      |  First Descr.  | First Comment
2      |  Second Descr. | Second Comment
```

Item rows (expected)

```
HeadID    | Name  | ResValue
1         | C0001 | 12
1         | C0002 | 23
2         | C0001 | 212
2         | C0002 | 223
2         | C0003 | 313
```

To achieve this, we need to add a RowId to the XML nodes somehow:

```
DECLARE @idoc int, @doc XML = '<Features>
  <Item>
   <Description>First Descr.</Description>
   <Comment>First comment</Comment>
   <C0001>12</C0001>
   <C0002>23</C0002>
  </Item>   
  <Item>
   <Description>Second Descr.</Description>
   <Comment>Second comment</Comment>
   <C0001>212</C0001>
   <C0002>223</C0002>
   <C0003>323</C0003>
  </Item>   
</Features>'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as HeadId,
    Description,
    Comment
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Features/Item', 1)
        WITH (
            Description nvarchar(255) 'Description',
            Comment nvarchar(4000) 'Comment'
    )
```

So far so good - the head looks good. Now the items (we need an unpivot to do this):

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as HeadId,
    unpvt.[Name],
    TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(unpvt.ResValue,',','.') AS DECIMAL(12, 6)) as ResValue
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Features/Item', 1)
        WITH (
            Description nvarchar(255) 'Description',
            Comment nvarchar(4000) 'Comment',
            C0001 nvarchar(20) 'C0001', 
            C0002 nvarchar(20) 'C0002', 
            C0003 nvarchar(20) 'C0003'
        ) x
        UNPIVOT ([ResValue] FOR [Name] IN (C0001,C0002,C0003)) AS unpvt
    WHERE TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(unpvt.ResValue,',','.') AS DECIMAL(12, 6)) <> 0
```

Unfortunately (but not unexpectedly) this wont work, as the HeadId is not 1,1,2,2,2 but 1,2,3,4,5 at the end.

```
HeadId  Name    ResValue
1   C0001   12.000000
2   C0002   23.000000
3   C0001   212.000000
4   C0002   223.000000
5   C0003   323.000000
```

So the question is: how to recover the correct HeadId for the item rows?
Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I can get the desired result by first getting a table result of items to get the item numbers, and extracting the element from that as a derived table.

Please keep in mind these functions can put a heavy load on the SQL instance so be careful executing them against large datasets. This result can be achieved in many different ways using XQuery and XPath functions so there might be more efficient ways of doing this.

```
DECLARE @doc XML = '<Features>
  <Item>
   <Description>First Descr.</Description>
   <Comment>First comment</Comment>
   <C0001>12</C0001>
   <C0002>23</C0002>
  </Item>   
  <Item>
   <Description>Second Descr.</Description>
   <Comment>Second comment</Comment>
   <C0001>212</C0001>
   <C0002>223</C0002>
   <C0003>323</C0003>
  </Item>   
</Features>'

select 
    HeadId, 
    Element.value('(local-name(.[1]))[1]','varchar(max)') Name, 
    Element.value('(.)[1]','decimal(12,6)') ResValue
from (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as HeadId, 
        items.query('(./*)') Item 
        from @doc.nodes('//Item') Features(Items)
    ) ItemList
cross apply ItemList.Item.nodes('/*[fn:contains(local-name(),"C0")]') xItems(Element)
```

Comment: Yeah, thx, I was able to reach the desired output using dense_rank() and cross apply also. It is a very slow solution. The @idoc and unpivot is much more faster. In the final problem the field names are C0001..C0500 :( But thx for your solution!